# Cordova image upload

Tags: php, cordova

I'm trying to find out how to upload files to PHP server using cordova plugins as shown in the URL below
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jc8djIHWY_k

I know cordova-plugin-intent has functionality for receiving an image by selecting "share via/open with" option and get the URL of the file

```
function deviceReady() {
console.log("Device Ready");
window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
if(url !== "") {
// url is the url the intent was launched with
document.querySelector("#test").innerHTML = "URL was "+url;
}
});
}
```

and cordova-plugin-file-transfer has functionality to transfer selected file to the server.

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
}
```

The problem is with cordova-plugin-file-transfer I have to select the file via file opener/file dialog, what I need to know is how to combine cordova-plugin-intent to get the image and send the file using cordova-plugin-file-transfer to the server without having to select the image from file dialog,  I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Photos you have on your desk or base64 style byte based photos? If it is byte based, you can convert the image to base64 and then process it. You can upload direct file  with cordova-plugin-file Check-it

Comment: Hi, yes cordova-plugin-file is the last option If there is no other way to do it, thank you for your suggestion